Creating bridge with bond as slave on a specific VLAN
I am on a Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS server. The network ports are already trunked. I am trying to setup a virtual bridge with a bond as a slave using netplan on a VLAN 202. Below is not working:
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-bond-bridge-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno3:
      dhcp4: false
    eno4:
      dhcp4: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [eno3, eno4]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  vlans:
    bond0.202:
        id: 202
        link: bond0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [bond0.202]
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
        search: []

I am unable to ping my Ubuntu host. What do I have wrong in my yaml file?

From the Netplan documentation on How to configure a VM host with bonded network interfaces and three VLANs, I've modified your Netplan config to account for one untagged VLAN and one tagged VLAN.
First, let's define your network:

VLAN1 untagged (management), IPv4: 192.168.1.0/24
VLAN202 tagged (guest), IPv4: 192.168.202.0/24
eno3, eno4 - bonded interfaces
bond0 - primary bond for untagged VLAN1
bond0-vlan202 - VLAN interface to connect to tagged VLAN202
br0 - bridge for interface bond0 on untagged VLAN1
br0-vlan202 - bridge on tagged VLAN202

$ cat /etc/netplan/00-bond-bridge-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno3:
      dhcp4: false
    eno4:
      dhcp4: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [eno3, eno4]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  vlans:
    bond0-vlan202:
        id: 202
        link: bond0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces: [bond0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
        search: []
    br0-vlan202:
      interfaces: [bond0-vlan202]
      dhcp4: false
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0
          via: 192.168.202.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]


Still not working. For VLAN202 where do I enter the gateway IP? Under br0 or br0-vlan202? The gateway for VLAN202 is 192.168.50.129 on my LAN. In this example, what is the gateway "192.168.202.1"? Where is this gateway coming from?

Which bridge should my VMs use, br0 or br0-vlan202? Neither bridge works for my VMs.

Disregard my last few comments. I figured it out on my own. I set br0 to be the default bridge for all of my VMs, and they now can communicate with all nodes on my network. Also, I found out that my Network Admin forgot to trunk the 2 ports for my ubuntu host. Once he trunked the 2 ports on the network switch, and I selected br0 for the default virtual bridge for my VMs, everything works now. Thank you for all of your help.

Glad you got it worked out! I will just add that in your original question, you didn't define what subnet you specified for your VLAN. So I arbitrarily picked 192.168.202.0/24 for the subnet and 192.168.202.1 for the gateway. I typically follow the idea that the third octet matches the VLAN number. Thus, VLAN202 will be something like 192.168.202.0/24 and VLAN10 would be 192.168.10.0/24. This isn't mandatory, but it makes logical sense in my head.
